# error accessing class variables within an ExternalInterface callback

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

Here's my actionscript (compiled with mxmlc, embedded into html, and the functions are called with js):

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class LyrePlayer extends Sprite {
        private var out:SoundChannel;
        private var player:Sound;

        public function LyrePlayer() {
            out = new SoundChannel();
            player = new Sound();
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("play", play);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("stop", stop);
        }

        private function play(url:String):void {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            player.load(request);
            if(out.position != 0) out.stop();
            out = player.play();
        }

        private function stop():void {
            out.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

This all works, sort of. I can play one file, and call `stop()` any number of times. But if I call `play()` a second time, it throws an error:

```
> flashObject.play("/static/test.mp3")
[the song plays]
> flashObject.stop()
[the song stops]
> flashObject.play("/static/test.mp3")
Error
arguments: undefined
message: "Error calling method on NPObject."
> flashObject.stop()
[no error]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but if you mean that if you remove the // from the out.stop() line in your play function you get an error, won't that trigger an error the first time you call play, since the out variable isn't set to an instance of SoundChannel yet?

Comment: I fixed that, and clarified my question. thanks.

Comment: Try changing the ExternalInterface callback names, lyrePlay instead if play.

Comment: @Samuel Neff - blah, same error.

Comment: Try assigning both player and out anew in each play call.

Comment: that works, but it causes a new instance of the song to play each time.

Comment: I think the issue is where I set `out = player.play()`. It works the first time, but then fails on `out.stop()` the next time.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to call `player.close()`, here's a [working example](http://code.google.com/p/invisiblemp3player/source/browse/trunk/%20invisiblemp3player%20--username%20fr3030@gmail.com/src/Main.as)